# How would I write a batch file to run an ffmpeg command on an entire directory?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

How would I create a batch file or simply a command to run `ffmpeg` instructions on an entire directory? I wish to transmux a folder of .ts files to .mp4

For individual files I use the command:

```
ffmpeg -i file.ts -acodec copy -vcodec copy file.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need a for loop to do that. So in a `batch-file`:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.ts) do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -acodec copy -vcodec copy "%%~ni.mp4"
```

I suggest you read up on some of the help available for this command via `cmd.exe` specifically focus on the *"substitution of FOR variable references"* section to understand how variables are expanded. simply run:

- `for /?`

You can find alot more helpful commands by running `help` and then running the shown commands with the `/?` switch available to each of them.

**SideNote** if you plan on running this from `cmd` and not a `batch-file` then we need to use single `%`

```
for %i in (*.ts) do ffmpeg -i "%i" -acodec copy -vcodec copy "%~ni.mp4"
```